# How to rasterize an object of class SpatialPolygonsDataframe in R

Tags: polygon, r, rasterization

When I read a polygon shapefile into R using rgdal, it was imported as an object of class `SpatialPolygonsDataframe`.

I need to rasterize the polygon, but the `rasterize{raster}` function requires it to be of the `SpatialPolygons` class.

**How do I convert it from the current data frame into the `SpatialPolygons` class?**

Comment: See my answer for rasterizing your polygons, but theanswer to your coercion question is to use the "as" method.  polys <- as(polys, "SpatialPolygons")

Answer (score 8):

Take a look at the help, the `rasterize` function in raster will, in fact, accept a `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame`.

Adapted from the second polygon example in `rasterize` help.

Create polygon examples

```r
library(raster)
polys <- spPolygons(rbind(c(-180,-20), c(-140,55), c(10, 0), c(-140,-60), c(-180,-20)),
                   rbind(c(-10,0), c(140,60), c(160,0), c(140,-55), c(-10,0)), 
                   rbind(c(-125,0), c(0,60), c(40,5), c(15,-45), c(-125,0)),
                   rbind(c(-180,10), c(0,90), c(40,90), c(145,-10),  
                         c(-25, -15), c(-180,0), c(-180,10)))
```

Coerce to SpatialPolygonsDataFrame and add data

```r
polys <- as(polys, "SpatialPolygonsDataFrame")
polys@data[,1] <- runif(nrow(polys))
class(polys)
```

Now, rasterize the polygon data and plot. The `r` raster is the reference raster for the rasterize function.

```r
r <- raster(ncol=90, nrow=45)
r.polys <- rasterize(polys, r, field = polys@data[,1], fun = "mean", 
                     update = TRUE, updateValue = "NA")
plot(r.polys)
```

One thing that I noticed is that at raster 2.4-30 under windows with R 3.2.3 the "field" argument is not recognizing the column index  (eg., field = 1). However, if I pass the argument the actual vector (as in my example) then it assigns the correct values to the resulting raster for all of the polygons. This can easily be recreated, with the example, using the syntax:

```r
r.polys <- rasterize(polys, r, field = 1, fun = "mean", update = TRUE, updateValue = "NA")`
```